# Can we mock constructor and check its parameters?

Tags: kotlin, mockk

With [mockk](https://github.com/mockk/mockk), to mock constructors, we can do something like ([taken from documentation](https://github.com/mockk/mockk#constructor-mocks)):

```
class MockCls {
  fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}

mockkConstructor(MockCls::class)

every { anyConstructed<MockCls>().add(1, 2) } returns 4

assertEquals(4, MockCls().add(1, 2)) // note new object is created

verify { anyConstructed<MockCls>().add(1, 2) }
```

I'd like to check on the parameters of my constructor. Something like:

```
class MockCls(val minValue: Int) {
  fun add(a: Int, b: Int) = minValue + a + b
}

mockkConstructor(MockCls::class)

every { anyConstructed<MockCls>(10).add(1, 2) } returns 14

assertEquals(14, MockCls(10).add(1, 2)) // note new object is created

verify { anyConstructed<MockCls>(10).add(1, 2) } // success
verify { anyConstructed<MockCls>(5).add(1, 2) } // fail
```

I didn't find any way to check constructor parameters right now.

Comment: Please submit feature request to GH issues

Comment: Done here https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/209

Answer (score 2):

This is now a feature in Mockk starting from [1.11.0](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/releases/tag/1.11.0).

```
mockkConstructor(MockCls::class)

// ...

verify { constructedWith<MockCls>(10).add(1, 2) } 
verify { constructedWith<MockCls>(5).add(1, 2)  }
```

See [Mockk - Constructor mocks](https://mockk.io/#constructor-mocks).

Comment: Which seems to be introduced as a result of [your feature request](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/209).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is currently not possible, as shown in the [feature request](https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/209) you kindly made.

Comment: feature request closed with fix in 1.11.0